# How to call procudure in jsp

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp

```
create procedure dat(
@d datetime,
@e datetime,
@LEFT datetime,
@day int)
as
begin 
set @d=(SELECT (DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0,DATEADD(DAY,6-DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE()),GETDATE())), 0) +28)) 
set @e=( select SYSDATETIME ()) 
SET @LEFT=@d-@e; 
set @day=(select DAY(@LEFT)) 
select region,cast((((TOTAL*55)/100)-(CAST((SUM(EMI)/100) AS DECIMAL(2,2))+CAST((SUM([REPO ARREAR])/100) AS DECIMAL(2,2))))/@day as decimal(3,3)) DRR from DCC GROUP BY TOTAL ,CIRCLE ,REGION  ORDER BY CIRCLE,REGION 
end
```

This is my procedure. I am writing this procedure in SQL server 2008.

```
try
{
 Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Repo;user=sa;password=sam123;");
String SQL=("{call [DCR].[dbo].[dat]()}");  
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(SQL);
rss=cs.executeQuery(); 
while(rss.next())
{
 float day=rss.getFloat(2);
}
}
catch(Exception e){
 }
```

This is my jsp code. I don't get the value in ResultSet. Please help me.

Comment: do not call code in jsp.  Learn about MVC and servlets etc.

Comment: also do not silently ignore exceptions - you are a bad bad boy.

Comment: Give me some example link related to my topic that i can learn

Comment: I think your code might actually be *so ugly* that it won't run.

Comment: try using google - it is your friend. I am not.

Answer (score 0):

You cant call a procedure from JSP and that is not the way to do it..It needs to be done in Java as follows

```
 CallableStatement sqlCallStmt = null; 
 sqlCallStmt = connection.prepareCall("{call Time(?,?)}")
 sqlCallStmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
 sqlCallStmt.setString(2,test);
 sqlCallStmt.execute();
```